# OleDbCommand, WHERE

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

With an Access table (CustomersTable) and two fields (CustomerID, CustomerName) ... field#1 is number, field#2 is text:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyName FROM CustomersTable WHERE CompanyName 'Zap'";
command.ExecuteReader();
```

results in error (missing operator) in query expression 'CompanyName 'Zap''.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyName FROM CustomersTable WHERE CompanyName VALUES(?)";
command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Zap";
command.ExecuteReader();
```

results in error (missing operator) in query expression 'CompanyName VALUES(?).

I suspect ExecuteReader() may be incorrect.

Comment: Missing an `=` sign.

Comment: It looks like You are not familiar with sql - it's first You need to learn. Your problem is the syntax in your queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `=` sign.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyName FROM CustomersTable WHERE CompanyName =  @p1";
```

Comment: The obvious.  Thanks!